# Getting list of files from a tree_id in AWS codeCommit

Tags: api, aws-codecommit

There is a way to get the list of files for a tree_id ?

Actually i can't find the right method to do this !
i can't go beyond the tree_id !!!

[GetCommit request inputs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetCommit.html)

```
{
   "commitId": "string",
   "repositoryName": "string"
}
```

Response

```
{
   "commit": { 
      "additionalData": "string",
      "author": { 
         "date": "string",
         "email": "string",
         "name": "string"
      },
      "committer": { 
         "date": "string",
         "email": "string",
         "name": "string"
      },
      "message": "string",
      "parents": [ "string" ],
      "treeId": "string"
   }
}
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3):

AWS CodeCommit currently does not have an API specific for this use. However, the GetDifferences API will do the recursive tree walk. So if you pass in null as the beforeCommitSpecifier, all changes prior to the afterCommitSpecifier value will be shown, and the file names are included in the response. Here's the documentation for GetDifferences API: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/codecommit/latest/APIReference/API_GetDifferences.html